# Extending Java application with user plugins

Tags: java, security, class, plugins, classloader

I am interested in extending my application with plug-ins. I made the Application to download videos from websites but it needs a valid URL to do this. The users could create a new plug-in for specific URL/domain and feed my application with valid URL.

I was doing this using jar files and URLClassLoaders. The problem with this approach is, that loaded classes have elevated privileges when they should only have permission to read from an URL.

Which is the best way to extend Java Application with plug-ins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OSGi might be the way to go, but it might also be a bit too advanced/complex for what you want to do. I used JPF in a small project a couple of years ago. I liked it.

http://jpf.sourceforge.net/

Comment: True, OSGi can be a bit of a pain to get you head around.

Comment: I read a bit about JPF some days ago but I didn't see anything to manage permissions. The app will load user untrusted plugins.

Comment: What do you mean by user trusted/untrusted? How will OSGI help you with that? What is it that you want to protect users from?

Comment: I mean that users can install an untrusted plugin and it could read data from disk and send it to a remote server because there isn't a way to limit the permissions using a classloader. I don't know if OSGi can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Check out OSGi, this is what eclipse uses to manage plugins. There are various implementations to choose from--eclipse has its own. OSGi will manage the classloader issues that can be complex.

Comment: Do I need to use Eclipse to use OSGI? I prefer Netbeans.

Comment: No. OSGi is an API specification. The eclipse foundation manages an implementation of the library. You are free to just include the library and develop in another environment. Your biggest challenge will be how easily you can integrate with you existing architecture.

Comment: That is not a problem. The 90% of my app is drawed in a paper. I started with the plugin mechanism because is the main part.

Comment: Check out @Kaj 's suggestion of jpf as well. I haven't used it but since you are early in dev it's best to try a few options out.

Comment: Sure, but as I said I didn't see nothing to control the security and the permissions of the plugins with JPF. Also is unattended. The last modification was in 2007.